# How to purchase multiple quantity of one product via In App Purchase at once in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, in-app-purchase

I have a project that provides services for period of time (Monthly - Yearly - etc.. )   and it's described as ***Non-Renewing Subscription***

These services have an option to work on multiple devices, so in this case when the costumer wants to add extra device he should pay for the service * 2

Question is how can I set the quantity for the purchased item.

**Used code for purchase**

```
void purchaseItem({required ProductDetails productDetails}) {
    final PurchaseParam purchaseParam = PurchaseParam(productDetails: productDetails);
    InAppPurchase.instance.buyNonConsumable(purchaseParam: purchaseParam); 
}
```

**Used library is** [in_app_purchase](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase)

Comment: hi, did you deal with that?

Comment: Nope, that was not achievable, so I had to work on some native code @LalaNaibova